# Can next.js and React.js work without Webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

Do you know how my configuration is working without webpack installed ? This configuration was originally made only to practice tests with Jest but the command "npm run dev" succeed to print a page. Is it a coincidence based on my code, my browser ?

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "fetch": "^1.1.0",
    "next": "10.1.3",
    "node-fetch": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.13.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.30.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-cli": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "jest-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.1.2",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: One does not need to explicitly install all the dependencies that other dependencies need. Webpack is installed when you install `next`. Open your lock file, you'll see all the dependencies and transitive dependencies. Moreover, Next.js has precompiled versions (using vercel/ncc) of many packages that don't appear even in the lock file.

Comment: Only pnp-webpack-plugin is visible in package-lock but it should be equivalent

Comment: Actually, webpack is precompiled (and is patched) by Next.js. Look inside `node_modules/next` for `dist/compiled/webpack` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js have internal config files for such cases. I think you can check next.config.js file to see the webpack configuration.

Have a look at this [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config).

Answer (score -4):

webpack is a React dependency : https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/main/package.json

Comment: That package.json file is used by react team during development (notice private: true at top), it is not same as the one they publish to npm. Webpack is bundled with next.js that's why the OP doesn't need to explicitly install it.